# How to display selected checkbox count in Angular2-multiselect?

Tags: angular, checkbox, multi-select

I want to print that '5 items selected' on multiselect dropdown.
here I attach an image of multiselect dropdown.
I have used the angular2-multiselect dropdown npm package.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zqo4e.png

here is my html code:

```
  <angular2-multiselect [data]="itemList" [(ngModel)]="selectedItems" [settings]="settings"
    (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)" (onDeSelect)="OnItemDeSelect($event)" (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)"
    (onDeSelectAll)="onDeSelectAll($event)" formControlName="skills">
  </angular2-multiselect>
```

here is my configuration settings.

```
this.settings = {
      text: "Select Skills",
      selectAllText: 'Select All',
      unSelectAllText: 'UnSelect All',
      badgeShowLimit: 2,   
    };
```

Comment: Where do you to show this label? in the dropdown or outside it?

Comment: in the dropdown

Comment: Its look like its available [here -> Select with custom trigger text](https://material.angular.io/components/select/examples) but not in that library

Comment: You can create an issue on GitHub with all necessary information, hope they will help you otherwise for me to raise a PR it will take 4-6days times

Comment: okay fine.can you suggest another library which provides this functionality?

Comment: why not angular materials mat-select??

Comment: ng-select is also there but not sure about this feature..just check it out

Comment: Angular material is provide this  feature?can you share an example like this?

Comment: Check this demo:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lavhcl

Comment: yes it's working.Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad it works!...

Answer (score 0):

Try to below way

```
selectedItems: any =  [
   { "id": 1, "itemName": "opt1" },
   { "id": 2, "itemName": "opt2" },
   { "id": 3, "itemName": "opt3" },
   { "id": 4, "itemName": "opt4" },
```

angular.json

```
 "styles": [
   "node_modules/angular2-multiselect-dropdown/themes/default.theme.css",
  ]
```

Comment: yes i have taken static array in my ts file. i get value of selected checkbox.but how can i display in html side?

Comment: put the css on angular.json
"node_modules/angular2-multiselect-dropdown/themes/default.theme.css",

Comment: Post your angular.json file and also share the which plug-ins version  angular2-multiselect-dropdown.

Comment: "styles": [
              "node_modules/angular2-multiselect-dropdown/themes/default.theme.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],

Comment: package version:4.6.3

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. it is working
  Component.html

```
<angular2-multiselect [data]="dropdownList" [(ngModel)]="selectedItems" 
    [settings]="dropdownSettings" 
    (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)" 
    (onDeSelect)="OnItemDeSelect($event)"
    (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)"
    (onDeSelectAll)="onDeSelectAll($event)">
</angular2-multiselect>
```

Number of Item Selected :{{selectedItems.length }}

{{item.itemName}}

Component.ts

```
 dropdownList = [];
    selectedItems = [];
    dropdownSettings = {};
    ngOnInit(){
        this.dropdownList = [
                              {"id":1,"itemName":"India"},
                              {"id":2,"itemName":"Singapore"},
                              {"id":3,"itemName":"Australia"},
                              {"id":4,"itemName":"Canada"},
                              {"id":5,"itemName":"South Korea"},
                              {"id":6,"itemName":"Germany"},
                              {"id":7,"itemName":"France"},
                              {"id":8,"itemName":"Russia"},
                              {"id":9,"itemName":"Italy"},
                              {"id":10,"itemName":"Sweden"}
                            ];
        this.selectedItems = [
                                {"id":2,"itemName":"Singapore"},
                                {"id":3,"itemName":"Australia"},
                                {"id":4,"itemName":"Canada"},
                                {"id":5,"itemName":"South Korea"}
                            ];
        this.dropdownSettings = { 
                                  singleSelection: false, 
                                  text:"Select Countries",
                                  selectAllText:'Select All',
                                  unSelectAllText:'UnSelect All',
                                  enableSearchFilter: true,
                                  classes:"myclass custom-class"
                                };            
    }
    onItemSelect(item:any){
        console.log(item);
        console.log(this.selectedItems);
    }
    OnItemDeSelect(item:any){
        console.log(item);
        console.log(this.selectedItems);
    }
    onSelectAll(items: any){
        console.log(items);
    }
    onDeSelectAll(items: any){
        console.log(items);
    }
```

stackblitz URL : [https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular2-multiselect-dropdown][1]

Comment: hey.thanks for your time.i want number of count like '3 items selected' not checked label on dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

```
selectAllText: string = 'Select All'  //we can add here count 

onItemSelect(item:any){
   console.log(item);
   console.log(this.selectedItems);
   this.dropdownSettings.selectAllText = 'Select All' + this.selectedItems.length
}
```

the count will be appended with Select All text.

Comment: using this code got result like select All 3. i want 3 items selected label in dropdown